# Non-ASCII character seen before =encoding in '[B<-d�>I<opts>]'. Assuming ISO8859-1

Tags: centos, wireshark, podman

I am trying to compile wireshark1.9.2 in centos.
I have done->

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make install
```

and this error is coming

```
[root@localhost build]# make install
Scanning dependencies of target auxiliary
[  0%] Generating AUTHORS-SHORT
[  0%] Generating capinfos.1, capinfos.html
[  0%] Generating dftest.1, dftest.html
[  0%] Generating dumpcap.1, dumpcap.html
[  0%] Generating editcap.1, editcap.html
[  0%] Generating asn2deb.1, asn2deb.html
/home/techie/wireshark-1.9.2/doc/asn2deb.pod around line 8: Non-ASCII character seen before =encoding in '[-a�I<ASN.1'. Assuming ISO8859-1
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 69.
make[2]: *** [asn2deb.1] Error 255
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/auxiliary.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@localhost build]# make install_sw
make: *** No rule to make target `install_sw'.  Stop.
```

if i go and remove the Non-ASCII character mentioned '�' which in the file is just a space in the file and replace it with a space the same error appears at a totally new location.

After replacing all such instances in the code I got the following error.

```
[root@localhost build]# make install
[  0%] Generating idl2deb.1, idl2deb.html
[  0%] Generating idl2wrs.1, idl2wrs.html
[  0%] Generating mergecap.1, mergecap.html
[  0%] Generating randpkt.1, randpkt.html
[  0%] Generating rawshark.1, rawshark.html
[  0%] Generating reordercap.1, reordercap.html
[  0%] Generating text2pcap.1, text2pcap.html
[  0%] Generating tshark.1, tshark.html
[  0%] Generating AUTHORS-SHORT-FORMAT, wireshark.pod
[  0%] Generating wireshark.1, wireshark.html
Wide character in printf at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Pod/Simple.pm line 539.
wireshark.pod around line 3549: Non-ASCII character seen before =encoding in 'KovE<aacute>ř'. Assuming UTF-8
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 69.
make[2]: *** [wireshark.1] Error 255
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/auxiliary.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@localhost build]#
```

Am I doing something wrong?
What should i do?
OS used: Centos
Wireshark Version i am trying to install: 1.9.2

Comment: Version 1.9.2? I can't find a download for something that ancient. There isn't even any such tag in the repo, but it would be around 9 years old at this point.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I really wouldnt use it if i didnt have to. Trust me. It kills me inside to compile this shit.

Comment: Well if you are desperate, just try to configure without building the docs, I assume they aren't your highest priority. Often there is some `--without-doc` type flag at the configure stage. I can't check exactly because i can't find version 1.9.2 tagged at all.